# How to style tags as StackOverflow does?

Tags: css

I am building a website which involves user comments and tags.

I wish to implement tags as they appear on the StackOverflow's Tags textbox after every question.

I am not able to figure out how to style a cross symbol after every tag and have a background for text inside the textbox as it's done on StackOverflow.

How can this be done?

Comment: Have you had a look at the code with something like Firebug - http://getfirebug.com/?

Comment: This is a valid question, should not have been closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Rikudo has already shown, a [larger image](http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3) which contains all the required images is used, along with some CSS to display only the required parts. This is the HTML used to display each tag:

```
<span class="post-tag">
    "the-tag"
    <span class="delete-tag" onmouseover="$(this).attr('class', 'delete-tag-hover')" onmouseout="$(this).attr('class', 'delete-tag')" title="remove this tag"></span>
</span>
```

The relevant CSS rules applied to class `delete-tag`:

```
background-image: url(img/sprites.png);
background-position: 0px -690px;
width: 14px;
height: 14px;
display: inline-block;
```

Answer (score 9):

Get Chrome, right click the tag or one of the bounding tags, choose 'inspect element'.

It's what i always do when i want to know how neat css stuff is done. And it'll lead you right to the sprite image.

Comment: Why the vote down. This is a very reasonable answer.

Comment: @Jeroen: I don't know why people voted you down, you answer was useful, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's an image in stackoverflow, part of a sprite actually. And they use it as a background image.

[image: StackOverflow Sprite]

Answer (score -1):

The cross is actually just a character: [×](http://enwp.org/%C3%97)

Comment: No, it's not. See my answer, and @Rikudo's answer.

Comment: I don't follow... where is `span.item-multiplier`?

Comment: I supposed we were talking about the sidebar. There is the tag list, the cross and the nr of taggings.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. I assumed we were talking about the tag input field, when you write a new question. I would remove my downvote, but I wasn't one of the people who downvoted!